# Breakout Sidebar Elements via CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a layout with multiple elements of different height stacked on mobile screens and some elements forming a sidebar for desktop, roughly looking like this:

[image: Layout]

My first idea was to achieve it via CSS grid, defining one row with two columns and then assigning the grid-area depending on the class (orange vs gray):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JensRavens/pen/abBJPym)

```
.layout {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 20px;
}

@media(min-width: 860px) {
  .layout {
    grid-template-areas: 'main sidebar';
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 2fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  }
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: main;
}
```

Problem: as multiple sidebar elements now occupy the same grid cell, they overlap instead of just flow on top of each other. I've been trying to wrap my head around alternative solutions for a few days now, but I couldn't find any so far that did not involve reordering the dom with JavaScript. Am I missing the obvious?

**EDIT**

Flexbox as stated in the answers does *not* solve this problem (if the position of elements within the list would be known upfront maybe, but this is not the case). Some elements go in the sidebar, some go in the main bar while having a fixed order in the mobile layout.

Comment: Your desktop layout **is not a grid**...so there is the start of the problem

Comment: You need two **independent** wrapper divs for each column. I suppose you could use `display:contents` at mobile size but support is not complete for that.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents#:~:text=display%3A%20contents%20causes%20an%20element's,grid%20or%20similar%20layout%20techniques.

Comment: @Jens As I think, you can do this easily by using flexboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox, then you can easily do this.

Refer following code,

```
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 860px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

set correct order of div (containers) as you need, (the following code is sample one)

```
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;" id="myRedDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="myGreenDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;" id="myPinkDIV"></div>
</div>
```

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}


/* Standard syntax */
div#myRedDIV   {order: 1;}
div#myBlueDIV  {order: 4;}
div#myGreenDIV {order: 3;}
div#myPinkDIV  {order: 2;}
```

Refer following links for more about Order in Flexbox

[Link1 --> About Flexbox Order](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/)

[Link2 --> About Flexbox Order](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-to-flexbox-ordering-reordering--cms-31564)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with flexbox. you can do it using **display:flex**, for more about the flex refer below sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
<p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

> This might not be the answer to your question! (cause I've changed the **grid** layout into **FlexBox**)

In this example I'm changing **flex-direction** via screen breakouts.
[More Information on CSS Flex box Direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

#### Code:

```css
        * {
            border: 1px solid coral;
            padding: 12px;
            margin: 12px;
        }

        .layout {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .layout>* {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .sidebar {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: grey;
        }



        @media(max-width: 860px) {
            .layout {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .layout>* {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .sidebar {
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .content {
                background-color: grey;
            }

            .content {
                background-color: green;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <div>
            <div class="content big">
                Here's some text
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar small">
                Sidebar Item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="content big">
                More Text
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar small">
                another sidebar Item
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```